# Generalized version of L’Hospital’s rule?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I was wondering if the following inequalities are true:$\liminf_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \leq \liminf_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \limsup_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \limsup_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ under some conditions on $f$ and $g$.

Under assumptions for L'Hospital's rule, if $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, then the above inequalities imply the conclusion of L'Hospital's rule. I think the above inequalities are the generalized version of L'Hospital's rule if they are right. Is it true?

Would you give me any comment about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That looks correct to me. Suppose $x\to c^+.$ Then for $x$ close to $c$ from the right,

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(c_x)}{g'(c_x)}$$

by Cauchy's general MVT. It follows that

$$\limsup_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \limsup_{x\to c^+}\frac{f'(c_x)}{g'(c_x)} \le \limsup_{x\to c^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

The last inequality follows from the fact that on the right we are considering suprema over larger sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I don’t understand the last statement. “over larger set”? what does it mean?

Comment: It seems that we need stronger assumption on f snd g than the ones in L’Hospital’s rule in order to make the inequlities true.