# Can L'Hôpital's rule be applied to the limit inferior of a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on an interval $I$ and differentiable on $I\setminus\{a\}$ for some $a\in I$, such that $f(a)g(a)$ is of an indeterminate form. Does
$$\liminf_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f'(a)}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(g(a)^{-1}\right)}=\liminf_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(a)}{g(a)^{-1}},$$
hold? If so, how can this be proven as a specific case of L'Hôpital's rule? The question is motivated by analysing oscillatory limits, specifically that of the distance function squared $$\lVert x\rVert^2=\frac{\arccos(\cos(2\pi x))^2}{4\pi^2},$$
which of course has a limit inferior of $0$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of using the [tag:proof-writing] tag for this question?

Comment: How can a proof be formulated to show that the theorem above holds (in the question, the line 'If so, how can...')?

Comment: The information concerning the [tag:proof-verification] tag says that it “should not be used to ask for a proof of a statement”. Isn't this exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks, I'll remove it. Also, when I say 'how to formulate' I mean more of an outline of useful lemmas rather than a step-by-step proof (i.e. should I proceed in the same way as with L'Hopital's rule by using Rolle's theorem and the generalised mean value theorem to show that the limits are equivalent?).

Comment: You can only say that ${\liminf _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}\leq \liminf _{x\to c}{\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}}\leq \limsup _{x\to c}{\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}}\leq \limsup _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule#Requirement_that_the_limit_exist and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2515008/42969.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could any stronger assumptions on $f$ and $g$ make the theorem in my question hold (or place a stricter bound $B$ on the error such that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\liminf_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\leq B$)?