Generalized Version of L'Hôpital's Rule
Recently when I was reading a paper I ran into the generalized L'Hôpital's rule which I've never seen before and the formulation of which I am writing below.

Theorem (Generalized Version of L'Hôpital's Rule). Let $-\infty \leq a < b \leq +\infty$, and let $f, g : (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions on
$(a, b)$ with $g'(x) \neq 0$ on $(a, b)$. Then in either of the
following two cases:

$\lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = \infty$,
$\lim\limits_{x \to b-} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = 0$,    we have $$\liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\leq
 \liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \limsup\limits_{x \to
 b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \limsup\limits_{x \to b-}
 \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$


Comparing it with the original version, whose proof I attached here, I don’t find the proof of the generalized version straightforward. I’ve spent a couple of hours trying to prove it without success so far. I think I’m close, but I’m not sure how to overcome some technical barriers. If anyone would like to help, I’d be more than happy to read their solution. However, I’d prefer a rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ proof since I’d like to share it with my students. Ideally, the proof should be similar in style to the original version’s proof. I know there is a proof on Wikipedia, but it is a bit sketchy. As I mentioned, I’d like to see a detailed proof that follows my reasoning, which I am going to write below.
My attempt: Let's try prove that $\liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\leq
 \liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and assume that $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
By definition, $\liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\sup\limits_{\delta>0} \inf \left\{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}:x\in \overset{\circ}{U}^-_{\delta}(b)\cap(a,b)\right\}$, where $\overset{\circ}{U}^-_{\delta}(b)$ is the deleted left $\delta$-neighborhhod of $b$, i.e., $\overset{\circ}{U}^-_{\delta}(b)=(b-\delta,b)$. It is not difficult to show that $$\liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\sup\limits_{\delta\in (0,b-a)} \inf \left\{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}:x\in (b-\delta,b)\right\}=\sup\limits_{\delta\in (0,b-a)} m(\delta),$$ where $m(\delta)=\inf \left\{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}:x\in (b-\delta,b)\right\}$.
So our goal to show that $\sup\limits_{\delta\in (0,b-a)} m(\delta)\leq \liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, or equivalently, $m(\delta)\leq \liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for every $\delta\in (0,b-a)$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose any $\delta\in (0,b-a)$ and fix it. Pick $y\in (b-\delta,b)$, let's say $y=b-\delta/2$. We know that $\exists \delta_1\in (0,b-y)$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta_1,b)$ we have: $|g(t)|\geq \dfrac{\max\{|f(y)|,|g(y)|\}+1}{\epsilon}$. In particular, this implies that for every $t\in (b-\delta_1,b)$, we have: $\left|\dfrac{g(y)}{g(t)}\right|\leq \epsilon$ and $\left|\dfrac{f(y)}{g(t)}\right|\leq \epsilon$. Now take any $x\in (b-\delta_1,b)$ then by Cauchy's theorem $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)}=\dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ for some $c\in (y,x)$. Therefore, $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)}\geq m(\delta)$.
And this where I'm stuck. So from here I need to derive that $m(\delta)\leq \liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. But I'd like to do this rigorously using $\epsilon-\delta$ and the definition $\liminf\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ which is $\sup\limits_{\eta\in (0,b-a)} \inf \left\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}:x\in (b-\eta,b)\right\}$.
I’d be very thankful if someone could continue my reasoning. Many thanks for your attention to my post!

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2515008/42969

@MartinR, thanks but I am aware of this post. I mentioned that I’d like to prove it rigorously based on my approach which I wrote above

@MartinR, maybe you know how to continue my reasoning?
